# XML Dataset is duplicated in xfa.datasetsNode after FillXfaForm is called when populating pdf form using itext7

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, itext7

As the title says im having an issue with the datasets xml property duplicating when populating a pdf using iTtext7. The PDF file gets populated but it causing an issue, when you open the pdf and complete manual change and saving it. All the pdf fields get wiped clean.

Is there a way to prevent to duplication or remove the duplicate code after?

The c# Code to populate pdf

```
       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templatePdfFile);
       reader.SetUnethicalReading(true);

       PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(OutputPdfFile);

       StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode();

       PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer, properties);
       PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
       XfaForm xfa = form.GetXfaForm();

       //Duplication happens here
       xfa.FillXfaForm(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlDoc.OuterXml)));
       xfa.Write(pdfDocument);
       pdfDocument.Close();
```

The Xml before calling FillfaForm

```
<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
  <xfa:data>
```

and after

```
<xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
  <xfa:data>
    <xfa:datasets xmlns:xfa="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/">
      <xfa:data>
```

Comment: Try innerxml instead of outer : xmlDoc.InnerXml

Comment: It produces the same issue :/

Comment: You have to advance the XmlReader using code like below : XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlDoc.OuterXml))
xfa = "http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/"
reader.ReadToFollowing("data",xfa);
xfa.FillXfaForm(reader)

Comment: It's producing an error "The XmlReader state should be End Of File after this operation." on the xfa.FillXfaForm(reader) line.

Comment: It means ReadToFollowing() is not finding the tag and moving to end of file.  It looks like the url for the xfa schema lost part of the string in my response.  Use the complete url from your posting.

Comment: No the tag is found. The code is now                 
XmlReader readerXml = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(workingMemory.xmlDoc.OuterXml));
 var tagFound = readerXml.ReadToFollowing("data", "http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/");
                if (tagFound)
                 xfa.FillXfaForm(readerXml);

Comment: https://www. went missing on that. When the tag is not found the error is the state should interactive.

Comment: I guess the error is due to reading in the middle of a xml you are not at the end of the code.  So the solution is to create a second XmlReader.  XmlReader reader2 = XmlReader.Create(reader); xfa.FillXfaForm(reader2)

Comment: there is only a Create(XmlReader reader, XmlReaderSettings settings); method is there any settings i need to do.

Comment: The create a default settings XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();  Usually the default settings are what is used by the XmlReader.Create() method.

Comment: It's given me the same result unfortunately.

Comment: I wasn't sure if creating the second reader would solve issue.  It was worth a try.  The solution then is to create a new Element with just the node.  So you can use the Xml Linq statement : XElement newElement = XElement.ReadFrom(reader);  This will only give the  node and nothing after the node.  Now you need a reader and can use StringReader.  So you can convert the XElement to a string. and StringReader strReader = new StringReader(newElement.ToString());  Then finally xfa.FillXfaForm(strReader);